# Wrapping a loop around a 'sed'-command processing many files in a single directory

Tags: shell-script, command-line, sed, bioinformatics

I have text-files containing many lines, of which some starts with ">" (it's a so-called *.fasta file, and the ">"s marks the beginning of a new information container):

```
>header_name1
sequence_info
>header_name2
sequence_info
```

I want to add the name of the file these lines are located in to the header. For example, if the file is named "1_nc.fasta", all the lines inside the file starting with > should have the label "001" added:

```
>001-header_name1
sequence_info
>001-header_name2
sequence_info
```

Someone nice provided me with this line:

```
sed 's/^>/>001-/g' 1_nc.fasta>001_tagged.fasta
```

Accordingly, all headers in 2_nc.fasta should start with "002-", 3_nc.fasta -> "003-", and so on.

I know how to write parallel job scripts, but the jobs are done so quickly, I think a script that serially processes all files in a loop is much better. Unfortunately, I can't do this on my own.

Added twist: 11_nc.fasta and 149_nc.fasta are not available.

How can I loop that through all the 500 files in my directory?

Comment: Note that the `/g` there is useless and only serves, if it serves at all, to make your command slower.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick.  I break the filename at the underscore to get the numerical prefix, and then use a `printf` to zero-pad it out to a three digit string.

```
for file in *.fasta; do
    prefix="$(printf "%03d" "${file%%_*}")"
    sed  "s/^>/>$prefix-/" "$file" > "${prefix}_tagged.fasta"
done
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I didnt test the other solutions, but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to do it

```
for f in *.fasta ; do echo sed "s/^>/>$(printf %03d "${f%%_*}")-/" "$f"; done
```

Test it as above for a preview, then remove `echo` to see what the contents will be:

```
for f in *.fasta ; do sed "s/^>/>$(printf %03d "${f%%_*}"-)/" "$f"; done
```

To make the new files, add redirection

```
for f in * ; do sed "s/^>/>$(printf %03d "${f%%_*}")/" "$f" > "$(printf %03d "${f%%_*}")_tagged.fasta"; done
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for bash:

```
for filename in *.fasta; do
  index="00${filename%_*}"
  addme="${index:((-3)):3}"
  sed "s/^>/>$addme-/g" "$filename" > "$addme"_tagged.fasta
done
```

The trick was to expand the index to three-digit. Then you need " instead of ' to allow for expansion of $addme

Comment: you are absolutely correct, I had misunderstood. Downvote converted to an upvote. Sorry! I deleted our previous exchange since I wasn't saying anything useful and you were just answering my nonsense.

Comment: @Zanna I feel I should put the record straight. Philippos was absolutely right and I was absolutely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
for n in 000{0..999}; do
   M=${n#???} N=${n##${n%???}}
   [ -f "${M}_nc.fasta" ] && sed -e "s/^>/&$N-/" < "${M}_nc.fasta" > "${N}_tagged.fasta"
done
```

## Summary

```
 n varies from 0000 -> 000999
 M varies from    0 ->    999 strip off the first 3 chars ${n#???}
 N is computed by removing the last 3 chars from n then what remains
   is then stripped , essentially performing the act of padding to 3 digits.

compute the filenames:
   fasda filename = ${M}_nc.fasta <------ input file to sed
   new filename   = ${N}_tagged.fasta <---- output file from sed

   sed command:   "s/^>/&$N-/"
```

Comment: A word of explanation would be in order here.  I can't tell what you're trying to do with your parameter expansion, because what you've used doesn't make sense.